# In my meditation app with React.js, how can I stop the background music together with the timer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, react-hooks, web-applications

I hope you can help me, I'll be really grateful!!

I built a meditation app with React.js ([here you can fin the deployed app](https://meditationtime.netlify.app)), but I want to improve it.

I want that when the timer stops (or the user press the stop button), the background music also stops, but at the moment the timer and the sounds are two components that doesn't talk to each other.

Let me paste some code:
there is a TimerPage.js that's the parent component, the SoundsGrid.js component is the child one and the SoundsItem.js component is the grandchild one.

TimerPage.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import style from "./TimerPage.module.css"
import Timer from "../../components/Timer/Timer"
import SoundsGrid from "../../components/SoundsGrid/SoundsGrid"
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar/Navbar"
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer"

export default function TimerPage() {
    const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0)
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
    const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false)
    const [keys, setKeys] = useState(0);
    const {isDark} = useContext(ThemeContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        let interval;
        if (isRunning) {
            interval = setTimeout(() => {
                if (seconds > 0 && seconds < 11) {
                    setSeconds((prevSeconds) => "0" + (prevSeconds - 1));
                } else if (seconds >= 11){
                    setSeconds((prevSeconds) => (prevSeconds - 1));
                } else if (minutes > 0) {
                    setMinutes(prevMinutes => prevMinutes - 1);
                    setSeconds(59);
                }
            }, 1000)
        } 

        if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
            setIsRunning(false);
            setSeconds(0);
            setMinutes(0);
        }

        return () => clearTimeout(interval);
    }, [minutes, seconds, isRunning]);

    //Start
    const startTimer = (e) => {
        if (minutes !== 0 || seconds !== 0) {
            setIsRunning(true);
        } else {
            window.alert("Insert a valid time");
        }
    }

    // Pause
    const pauseTimer = () => {
        setIsRunning(false);
    }
    
    // Stop
    const stopTimer = () => {
        setIsRunning(false);
        setSeconds(0);
        setMinutes(0);
    }
    

    //Select a time from the buttons
    const changeTimer = (e) => {
        setIsRunning(false);
        setSeconds(prevSeconds => {
            prevSeconds = e.target.getAttribute("value")
            return (
                `${Math.floor(prevSeconds % 60) + "0"}`
            )
        });
        setMinutes(prevMinutes => {
            prevMinutes = e.target.getAttribute("value")
            return (
                `${Math.floor(prevMinutes / 60)}`
            )
        })

        //It changes the lenght of the circle by the user select a different time 
        setKeys(keys => {
            keys = e.target.getAttribute("value")
            return (
                `${keys}`
            )
        })
    }

    
    return (
        <main className={`${isDark ? style.timerPage__dark : style.timerPage__light}`}>
            <Navbar />
            <h1>MEDITATION TIME</h1>
            <p>Life is a rush but you can take a moment for yourself everyday.</p>
            
            <Timer 
                minutes={minutes}
                seconds={seconds}
                isRunning={isRunning}
                keyss={keys}
                setIsRunning={setIsRunning}
                changeTimer={changeTimer}
                startTimer={startTimer}
                stopTimer={stopTimer}
            />
            
            <div className={style.controlButtons}>
                {!isRunning && (
                    <button  onClick={startTimer} className={`${isDark ? style.button__dark : style.button__light}`}>
                        <span><MdPlayArrow size={25}/>Play</span>
                    </button>
                )}
                {isRunning && (
                    <button  onClick={pauseTimer} className={`${isDark ? style.button__dark : style.button__light}`}>
                        <span><MdPause size={25} />Pause</span>
                    </button>
                )}
                <button  onClick={stopTimer} className={`${isDark ? style.button__dark : style.button__light}`}>
                    <span><MdStop size={25} />Stop</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <SoundsGrid />
            <Footer />
        </main>
    )
}
```

Then SoundsGrid.js:

```
import React, { useContext, useRef } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../context/ThemeContext";
import style from "./SoundsGrid.module.css";
import soundData from "../../data/SoundtrackData";
import SoundItem from "../SoundItem/SoundItem";

export default function SoundsGrid(childToParent) {
    const {isDark} = useContext(ThemeContext)
    
    const sounds = soundData.map(item => {
        return <SoundItem 
            key = {item.id}
            item = {item}
        />
    });

    return (
        <div className={`${isDark ? style.sounds__dark : style.sounds__light}`}>
            <span><p>Find out YOUR perfect sound, you can select multiple tracks at a time.</p></span>
            <section className={`${isDark ? style.soundsGrid__dark : style.soundsGrid__light}`}>
                {sounds}
            </section>
            <button >Reset</button>
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

and finally SoundItem.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../../context/ThemeContext";
import { SettingsContext } from "../../context/SettingsContext";
import style from "./SoundItem.module.css";
import { BsFillVolumeOffFill, BsFillVolumeDownFill } from "react-icons/bs";


export default function SoundItem(props) {
    const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
    const audioRef = useRef();
    const progressBar = useRef();
    const {isDark} = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const {isRunning} = useContext(SettingsContext)
    

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isPlaying) {
            audioRef.current.play();
        } else if (isRunning === false) {
            audioRef.current.pause();

        } else {
            audioRef.current.pause();
        }
    }, [isPlaying]);

    const changeRange = (e) => {
        audioRef.current.volume = e.target.value / 100;
    };

    const setSounds = (() => {
        setIsPlaying((prev) => !prev)
    });


    return(
        <div className={style.soundItem__container}>
            <button 
                className={`${isDark ? style.soundItem__dark : style.soundItem__light}`}
                onClick={setSounds}
                style={{backgroundColor: isPlaying ? "#FFFFFF" : "", color: isPlaying ? "#000046" : "" }}
            >
                {props.item.icon}
            
                <audio loop volume ref={audioRef} src={props.item.soundUrl} type="audio/mpeg">
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                </audio>
            </button>
            {isPlaying ? 
                <div>
                    <BsFillVolumeOffFill />
                    <input
                        type="range"
                        className={style.progressBar}
                        defaultValue="100"
                        ref={progressBar}
                        onChange={changeRange}
                    />
                    <BsFillVolumeDownFill/>
                </div>
            : "" 
            }
            <p className={style.soundItem__name}>{props.item.title}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I previously tried to lift up the audioRef to SoundsGrid, but the result is that all the sounds start and stop together or strange things happens, I think because I used the map method on the sounds array.
I also created a Sound Context for this but it doesn't work as well, I think because of the useRef and .map() .

I'd like tho find a way to stop(or pause) the selected sounds while the timer stops or the user press the stop (or pause) button.
I hope to be clear, and could someone help me please? Thank you very much!
Every opinion is well accepted :)